# Showing polygon in OpenLayers Timeline?

Tags: polygon, openlayers, kml, time

I am trying to use the OpenLayers TimeLine library with a kml file.

I used the  available example for kml in [github](https://github.com/volpino/openlayers-timeline), but it shows points instead of polygon.

How can I display polygon the TimeLine library of OpenLayers?

Comment: Don't expect anything from this library if using OpenLayers 3 as the "TimeLine library of OpenLayers" you refer is only for OpenLayers version 2 (no maintenance for this plugin since 4 years according to the Github repo)! Is it a tag error in the question?